Automatically placing a hold on google cloud storage objects after 24 hours
What is the best approach to placing a hold on an object in google cloud storage automatically after the file reaches a certain age? A default hold policy on a bucket would put a hold on right away, so that does not work. Google Cloud Storage Object Lifecycle Management does not apply to this because placing a hold is not one of the available actions for Object Lifecycle Management. Is a Cloud Function something that would be good for this kind of thing? If so, what would be a good strategy when using one to solve this need?
I looked in Object Lifecycle Management, which is able to perform actions based on the age of a stored object, but placing a hold on an object is not an available action. I would like this functionality to be automatic, and not based on any extra resources, like a managed vm, hence why I am hoping for some thoughts on if Google Cloud Function could be a good solution.
The two main ideas I have currently: run it once a day to filter on files in the bucket with no hold, check their age, and apply a hold if their age is over 24 hours. The "smarter" way, which I would prefer, is to have a cloud function trigger on object creation for that bucket and sleep for 24 hours? Or somehow schedule another function for 24 hours in the future?
